# R Loop and large dataframes low performance

Tags: r, dataframe, performance, for-loop

I have two list of dataframes and also another big dataframe which I am using in my code.
The code is working, however, since I am looping for like 10000 times it takes  a lot of time. A very similar code in VBA just runs a few seconds.
I am using multiple librarys like dplyr, rlang and readr.
my dataframe consists of x rows, the first column has IDs for which i am trying to calculate different types of losses and several more columns with numerical values.

so my dataframe looks something like this:

> ```
> n <- 1000
> dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
>               category=sample(1:13, n, replace=TRUE),
>                value1=rnorm(n),
>                 value2=rnorm(n),
>             value3=sample(seq(0,1,0.1),n,replace=TRUE),
>             value4=rnorm(n),
>            value5=sample(4:20,n,replace=TRUE),
>            value6=sample(2:18,n,replace=TRUE), 
>           value7=sample(0:24,n,replace=TRUE))
> ```

list1 and list 2 are list of dataframes, the column names of each dataframe should be equal to the column number, I did not know how to recreate it.

> ```
> list1<-lapply(1:13,function(x){matrix(rnorm(24*25),nrow=24,ncol=25)})
> ```

> ```
> list2<-lapply(1:13,function(x){matrix(rnorm(24*20),nrow=24,ncol=20)})
> names(list2)<-1:13
> names(list1)<-1:13
> ```

To determine the losses I need the dataframes in the lists, because for each category I need to use the corresponding dataframe. Each ID is mapped to a certain category.

Further I have several for loops. In one I am taking values out of the dataframe.
What I am trying to do is, at the end to put the result of loss_1_i and loss_2_i into a vector and use the results for further calculations.

> ```
> loss_1<-vector(mode="numeric",length=10000)
> loss_2<-vector(mode="numeric",length=10000)
> for (i in 1:10000){
> ```

Here I am taking random numbers for each category, I have 13 categories.

> ```
>        for(k in 1:13){
>         random_number_1[k]=rnorm(1,0,1)}
> loss_1_i=0
> loss_2_i=0
> ```

Here I am looping through the number of IDs

> ```
> for (j in 1:n){ 
>  category=as.numeric(df[j,c("category")])
>  value1=as.numeric(df[j,c("value1")])
>  value2=as.numeric(df[j,c("value2")])
>  value3=as.numeric(df[j,c("value3")])
>  value4=as.numeric(df[j,c("value4")])
>  value5=as.numeric(df[j,c("value5")])
>  value6=as.numeric(df[j,c("value6")])
>  value7=as.numeric(df[j,c("value7")])
>  random_number_2=rnorm(1,0,1)        
>  my_col_name=as.numeric(names(list1[[category]]))
>  my_col_name=sort(my_col_name,decreasing=TRUE) 
>    test=random_number_2*sqrt(value3)+ random_number_1[category]*sqrt(1-value3)
> ```

This part takes the longest

> ```
>  score_new=24
>   for(k in my_col_name){
>       k=as.character(k)
>        if (test>=list1[[category]][value7,c(k)]{
>            score_new= as.numeric(k)
>            k=as.numeric(k)
>        }
> }
> ```

> ```
>  variable1=as.numeric(list2[[category]][score_new,value5])
>  variable2=as.numeric(list2[[category]][value7,value6])
>    if (score_new==24){
>      loss_1_i=loss_1_i+value1*value2
>      loss_2_i=loss_2_i+value1*value2
>        }else{ 
>         loss_2_i=loss_2_i+0.6*(variable1- 
>         variable2)*value1*value2}
>    } loss_1[i]=loss_1_i
>      loss_2[i]=loss_2_i
> }
> ```

I already now that the part where I determine score_new takes the longest. Does someone know how I can improve this code?
the number x is also a large number close to 1000.

I am very thankful for any help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. A few questions: (1) Is `df` in your loop supposed to be `dat`? (2) Why are you copying the contents of your objects to new variables in your loops, rather than just accessing them? This is a potential cause of slowdown. (3) This has the code smell of something that is written with another language in mind, one that doesn't have R's vectorisation. <https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html> Is there a reason why you had to do it this way? If you could vectorise it, it would be much faster.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. 1) Yes it is supposed to be dat 2) good remark, I don't know exactly how I can vectorise it. Can you give me an example

Comment: To be honest, it is hard for me to tell what you are trying to achieve in this code; one of the problems of long for loops is that they obscure the intent of code, especially for unfamiliar problems. You would have to do something like write your logic out as pseudocode, or else maybe someone more familiar with the problem will see the question.

Comment: The matrices in `list1` have consistent dimensions in your example. Will that always be the case? Same for `list2`?

Comment: No it's not always the case.

Comment: And actually they should not be matrices but dataframes, because I need the column names of each data frame, but I did not know how to replicate it here, because I read multiple dataframes  and put them into a list.

Comment: If the column names are just `1:ncol`, you don't need them. Also, why is `score_new` initialized to 24? You seem to want to set `score_new` to the first index of `list1[[category]][value7,]` that is less than or equal to `test[j]`. Is that right?

Comment: Do the number of rows of the matrices in `list1` always match the number of rows of the corresponding matrix in `list2`?

Comment: the names of the column are not just 1:ncol, and yes i want to find the first index, I also tried score_new=as.numeric(names(list1[[category]])[max.col(list1[[category]][value7,]<=test[j],ties.method="first")]) but in the loop it took also a long time, and the rows in matrices in list1 do not match the rows in list2

Comment: What would be an example of one of the sets of column names? I see `my_col_name=as.numeric(names(list1[[category]]))`, so presumably they are numeric. Also, something still doesn't smell right with `score_new`. It is used to index a row of `list2[[category]]`, but it takes the numeric value of one of the column names of `list1[[category]]`, which may have more columns than `list2[[category]]` has rows.

Comment: You can use the `dimnames` argument of `matrix` to add column names. E.g., `dimnames = list(NULL, sample(25))`.

Comment: the colnames are in general numbers from 0 to 24, but in some dataframes there are for example not 25 rows but 23 because the numbres 21 and 22 are not relevant for that dataframe. therefore I am taking the names of the list as my_col_name. since this is a reduced example, it might seem like score_new is not correct. However the dataframes in both lists match in the way that there is no problem with the number of rows/columns.

Comment: So my actual problem is not the colnames of the dataframes or how I can recreate it, I am just not understanding why the for loop where I determine score_new takes so long. And if there is a smoother solution to do these loop

Comment: The best way to speed this up is to vectorize, and I see several ways it could *potentially* be vectorized, but I can't work out for sure how the data are being accessed. I recommend updating your example to something that is fully representative of the structure of your data and that will run. When I try to run your code, it errors.

Comment: Also, if the dimensions of the matrices can be potentially different, defining `list1` and `list2` with something like `lapply(1:13,\(i){matrix(rnorm((nr <- sample(20:30, 1))*(nc <- sample(20:30, 1))), nr, nc, dimnames = list(NULL, 0:(nc - 1)))})` will make it clear.

Comment: Also, if the column names include 0, couldn't `score_new` take the value of 0? In that case, what is supposed to happen with `variable1 <- as.numeric(list2[[category]][score_new,value5])`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I believe is similar to what is being attempted. It is almost fully vectorized other than the outermost loop. The original code does not run without error, so I can't compare timings.

Note that I changed the number of rows of the matrices in `list2` to match the number of columns of the matrices in `list1`, otherwise it won't run without error since the column numbers from the matrices in `list1` are used as row indices for the matrices in `list2`.

```
library(Rfast)

system.time({
  # pre-calculate value1*value2
  dat$value1_2 <- dat$value1*dat$value2
  # Convert list1 and list2 into 3D arrays. Pad the second dimension of arr1 with
  # an extra column so `score_new <- pmin(max.col(rnorm(n)*sr + rnorm(1)*sr1 >=
  # m), nc1[dat$category])`.
  arr1 <- array(-Inf, c(max(nr1), max(nc1) + 1L, length(list1)))
  arr2 <- array(-Inf, c(max(nc1), nc2, length(list2)))
  
  for (i in seq_along(list1)) {
    arr1[1:nrow(list1[[i]]), 1:ncol(list1[[i]]), i] <- list1[[i]]
    arr2[1:nrow(list2[[i]]), 1:ncol(list2[[i]]), i] <- list2[[i]]
  }
  # get list1[[category]][value7,] as a matrix with n rows
  m <- with(
    dat,
    matrix(
      arr1[
        sequence(
          rep(ncol(arr1), n),
          (category - 1L)*prod(dim(arr1)[1:2]) + value7,
          nrow(arr1)
        )
      ], n, byrow = TRUE
    )
  )
  # pre-calculate variable2
  variable2 <- with(dat, arr2[cbind(value7, value6, category)])
  # pre-calculate the square roots
  sr <- sqrt(dat$value3)
  sr1 <- sqrt(1 - dat$value3)
  
  for (i in 1:1e4){
    score_new <- pmin(max.col(rnorm(n)*sr + rnorm(1)*sr1 >= m), nc1[dat$category])
    bln <- score_new == nc1[dat$category]
    idx <- which(!bln)
    loss_1[i] <- sum(dat[bln, "value1_2"])
    loss_2[i] <- with(
      dat,
      sum(value1_2[bln]) + 0.6*sum((arr2[cbind(score_new[idx], value5[idx], category[idx])] - variable2[idx])*value1_2[idx])
    )
  }
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    5.73    0.36    6.10
```

Data:

```
n <- 1e3
nr1 <- sample(20:30, 13, 1)
nc1 <- nr2 <- sample(20:30, 13, 1)
nc2 <- 20L

dat <- data.frame(id=1:n,
                  category=sample(1:13, n, replace=TRUE),
                  value1=rnorm(n),
                  value2=rnorm(n),
                  value3=sample(seq(0,1,0.1),n,replace=TRUE),
                  value4=rnorm(n),
                  value5=sample(4:nc2,n,replace=TRUE),
                  value6=sample(2:18,n,replace=TRUE))
# value7 refers to the row number of list1[[category]] and the row number of
# list2[[category]]
dat$value7 <- sapply(pmin(nr1[dat$category], nr2[dat$category]), sample.int, size = 1L)

list1 <- lapply(1:13,\(i){matrix(rnorm(nr1[i]*nc1[i]), nr1[i], nc1[i])})
list2 <- lapply(1:13,\(i){matrix(rnorm(nr2[i]*nc2), nr2[i], nc2)})
loss_1 <- loss_2 <- numeric(1e4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I just made a simple example of the lists here. In my actual lists I have dataframes with different row and column numbers. Therefore the construction of this 3 dimensional array fails. The dataframes in list2 all have the same column numbers, but the row numbers are different. In list1 both the row and col numbers differ for each dataframe.

Comment: The construction of the 3D array should not fail. This code creates the array with the first dimensions equal to the maximum row numbers in the list of matrices and the second dimension equal to 1 plus the maximum column numbers in the list of matrices. Any extra space is padded with `-Inf`.

Comment: As I mentioned in previous comments, there are a few inconsistencies with the indexing in the example code you provided. For example, `value7` is used as a row index for the matrices in both `arr1` and `arr2`, yet it includes zeros, which will result in empty vectors. Also, `score_new` appears to be able to take values between 1 and the number of columns of the matrices in `arr1`, and then it is used as a row index for the matrices in `arr2`, yet the number of columns of the matrices in `arr1` do not match the number of rows of the matrices in `arr2`.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how it works with variable-dimensioned matrices. I realize it may not reflect your actual data, but I did my best to try to give some ideas how it might be vectorized. To get an answer that does reflect your data/problem, I recommend updating your question to be *representative of your actual data* and *reproducible* (i.e., it should run without error and produce the desired result).